# Performing http header checks in C

Tags: c, networking, websocket, libpcap

I want to perform HTTP header checks in C, here is the code that I am using to do the same. But I am unfortunately not getting the desired output. This is the code that I have used to implement the checks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    const char *payload="GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Host: 192.168.43.135:12345\r\n"
    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
    "Pragma: no-cache\r\n"
    "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n"
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
    "Origin: file://\r\n"
    "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n"
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36\r\n"
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch\r\n"
    "Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4\r\n"
    "Sec-WebSocket-Key: bKdPyn3u98cTfZJSh4TNeQ==\r\n"
    "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits\r\n"
    "\r\n"
    "[Full request URI: http://192.168.43.135:12345/]"
    "[HTTP request 1/1]"
    "[Response in frame: 6]";
    const char *token;
    token = strtok(payload, "\r\n");
    while (token)
    {
        
        if(strcmp(token,"GET / HTTP/1.1")==0)
        {
            printf("Current token: %s\n", token);
            printf("Correct Version\n");
        }
        else if(strcmp(token,"Connection: Upgrade")==0)
        {
            printf("Current token: %s\n", token);
            printf("Connection upgraded\n");
        }
        else if(strcmp(token,"Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13")==0)
        {
            printf("Current token: %s\n", token);
            printf("Correct version\n");
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried both with both `strtok()` and `strstr()` and I am getting the incorrect outputs in both the cases.[The output shown while using strstr()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boGUN.png) [The output shown while using strtok()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELEdA.png). The output required should be

```
Current token: GET / HTTP/1.1
Correct version
Current token: Connection: Upgrade
Connection upgraded
Current token: Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Correct version
```

Comment: The first parameter to `strtok` needs to be a writable buffer. You are passing in a constant string. Change `const char *payload` to be `char payload[]`

Comment: yeah,`strtok` needs a  writable buff, and you need to parse next token use `token = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");`